# How do you convert an integer with more than 10 digits into a string in C?

Tags: c, string, int

```
//What I have that works on integers with 10 digits or less:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Card number? ");
    int i = GetInt();
    char str[100];
    snprintf(str, 64, "%i", i);
    printf("Your string: %s\n",str);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some detail to improve your question, such as: What are you expecting to happen and what actually does happens? If your sample code causes an error, then what is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is perhaps rather "how do you work with integers with more than 10 decimal digits of precision?"

The answer is [by using a big-number library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries) since you cannot assume the built-in types to support that many digits, typically.

Or, you can perhaps get away by using

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

and using `uint64_t`, that will give you integers up to 9223372036854775808 (more than 18 digits).

Comment: I would even suggest [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/) as a bignum library usable in C.